# JSTL Check if resource available or not

Tags: jstl

Is there anyway to check if required resource available or not

My code

```
<img id="photo" src="http://localhost:8081/test.png" />
```

Now suppose my image name is `test.png`

now what i want to do is check if `http://localhost:8081/test.png` available or not

e.g `<c:if test="${resource}">`

if not available i want to put `default.png` as `http://localhost:8081/default.png` in the src which is available that i know for sure.

and If it is available then i will put src value to `http://localhost:8081/test.png`

How to do this??

Comment: That's not as easy as it sounds, because basically what you're asking is if the webserver is physically capable of providing that image through a HTTP request.

Comment: yes. is it not possible??

Comment: Well where are the images stored? If they are in some directory on the server, you could check with a simple File object if an image exists or not. If they are part of a deployed WAR or EAR, I'd see if there is a client side / javascript way to do it in stead.

Comment: It is possible but you will have to check in a http request if that resource is present and can be served

Comment: the images are stored in a separate server (nginx) but both tomcat and nginx are in the same PC

Comment: Then Jabir's comment is probably the only reliable way; you'd have to do a HTTP request from Java code to know if the resource can be served or not before the page is rendered.

Comment: Using Java i can do this easily, i know that. but i was wondering if i could do that from front end

Comment: Then why post this as a java question which is back end!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript). Please note this is not JSTL based solution as stated in question.

```
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should develop your own custom tag, that returns one picture or another depending on the availavility of the first.

You should use two parameters: One for the image that may be available or not, and another for the "default" image.

Here's a good introduction to the subject.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm