# How to replace HTML img broken by missing or erroring image src

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have following code:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="20" height="20"> some content here
```

When image is not found, it shows like following:

[image]

> This behavior is different according to browsers.

I want to display transparent box(plain white) or some good looking container(empty box) that will look same in all browsers. I have tried with alt tag, but it does not work.

How can I achieve this ?

Demo: [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dnk5e1pa/)

```html
<img src="img_girl.jpg" width="20" height="20"> some content here
```

Comment: Test first for missing image. If image is missing, show your preferred "error" image.

Comment: @RobMoll how to show preferred error image ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272956/how-to-check-whether-an-image-is-a-broken-image-or-not-in-javascript/30273194](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272956/how-to-check-whether-an-image-is-a-broken-image-or-not-in-javascript/30273194)

Comment: @RobMoll I want to implement in Angular 9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `error` handler with `onError`.  ***But make sure to cancel the `onError` handler after it is invoked***, because if your backup-image is missing, this will cause an infinite loop of server requests -- *not good!*  Handle it like this...

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="20" height="20" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='imageNotFound.gif';">
```

By setting `this.onerror=null;`, we are preventing an infinite loop of server requests.  Then `imageNotFound.gif` will display for users if the image is there.

POD (Source: [MDN Web Docs: GlobalEventHandlers.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror))....

> The reason we have the this.onerror=null in the function is that the browser will be stuck in an endless loop if the onerror image itself generates an error.

Comment: thanks for answer. its working as expected, I observed that it is not working in firefox browser. Is it something missing to add for firefox additionally ..??

Comment: @chirag Hrm, I'm not sure, but the documentation at MDN says that FireFox version 1.0 supported this, and, at the very bottom of the page, it summarizes support as "Full support".  Not sure what could be happening, maybe cache?  Are you inspecting and seeing the onerror call?  What does the console log say?  Any errors?

Comment: yes I am getting onerror call. but my this.src is not being called

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Angular you can simply use `onError` to show your fallback/error image in case that your initial `src` could not be loaded:

```
<img [src]="invalidPath" onError="this.src='images/angular.png'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the backend programming to determine if the path exists and contains an image then display it. If the path does not exist or does not contain an image then you can decide to display a default image or any component of your choice.

In PHP you can do it as follows:

```
<?php
    if (file_exists('test.jpg')) {
        echo "<img src='test.jpg'>";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='default.jpg'>";
    }
?>
```