# Check if local image exists returns always true

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I try to check if an image is available in my mobile PhoneGap App with the following code:

```
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

The images are stored on the device and some images are missing. But the returned status is always 200 even if the image doesn't exist. I found the solution here: [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript) 
It seems to work for everyone. What am i missing?

Edit: Like i say in my question the suggested solustion doesn't work and i want to know why? That's no possible dublication. Please read my question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript)

Comment: You post a possible duplication of the exact link i link in my question?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal could you please explain me how your dublication could even help me in the slightest way?

Comment: probably he didn't read your answer correctly @JonasSchafft !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use the [File Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) and call the `getFile` method - see [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for more info on usage.  Here is a quick look at what you will want to be using as a starting point:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('filename.jpg', {create: false, exclusive: false}, 
     function(fileEntry) {
          //file exists
          console.log("Woohoo the file exists!");
     }, fileErrorHandler);
}

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onInitFs, errorHandler);

function fileErrorHandler(){
     //file doesn't exist
     //now go get the file
     callYourGetFileHere();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help. I wanted to know why the normal way doesn't work, Thanks anyway