# How do I delete an image element if it's source file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, image, loading

I am making a site with a popup. The popup is supposed to have up to 12 images in it. I am calling my images pizza1.jpg,  pizza2.jpg,  pizza3.jpg, and so on.

Is there any way with pure JavaScript to make the images show up only if there is actually a file with the name I have told it to look for?

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript) is similar, but all the answers are complicated, and only moderately related.

Comment: are you fetching them via AJAX?

Comment: Please check the answer there and if image does not exist, than do not show it. If you need further assistance, try to be more accurate, add some code.

Comment: The other question's answers are only complex solutions to a problem much more complicated than mine. The accepted answer to this question is simple for my situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `onError` event for remove object from your popup:

```
<img src="src" onError="removeElement(this);" />
```

Check if it will work:

```
function removeElement(element) {
     element.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onerror) event of the `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [Image instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) and use its onload event to see if it has loaded. If so just append the image to whatever element.

Demo

```js
var imgurls = [
  "https://placekitten.com/g/64/64",
  "https://placekitten.com/g/32/32",
  "https://placekitten.com/g/none/200",
  "https://placekitten.com/g/100/100",
  "https://placekitten.com/g/24/24"
];

imgurls.forEach(function(url){
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = onImageLoad;
  img.src = url;
});
  
function onImageLoad(){
  document.body.appendChild(this);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
</div>
```