# Missing background image placeholder

Tags: html, css, image

Although there seems to be plenty of answers regarding broken `<img>` handling to show replacement images when the original could not be loaded, I can't seem to find a solution regarding missing background-images.

**Question:** How can I show another background-image if the original background-image was not loaded?

I apply the background-images like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('img/test.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: The only solution I get is checking with JS if the ressource is available (using something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript), and change the `div` property if it does not exist (or maybe check before setting the url).

Comment: Or another solution, would be using, as url, a script redirecting the request to the image you want. With PHP, use something similar to this : `<?php header( file_exists("img/test.jpg") ? "Location: img/test.jpg"  : "Location: img/image_not_available.jpg" ); ?>` (Of course, this is only a draft.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to check the availability of the image.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'img/test.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    // create a script that will append style using background-image with this source
}

img.onerror = function() {
    // create a script that will append style using background-image with new source
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Option → JavaScript:**

You can check if the image is available in JavaScript by sending an AJAX request as follows:

```
function isAvailable(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        return xhttp.status != 404;
    };
    xhttp.open('head', url, false);
    xhttp.send();
};
```

You can now use the above function to make the check and set the appropriate url:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
imgUrl = isAvailable("main-url") ? "main-url" : "backup-url";
element.style.backgroundImage = imgUrl;
```

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Option → PHP:**

If you want to make the check server-side, then it gets a lot easier as you can use the native **`file_exists()`** function:

```
<?php
    $img_url = file_exists("main-url") ? "main-url" : "backup-url";
?>
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_url; ?>);"></div>
```

Comment: Please be aware that the SO documentation link will become non-functional in the near future, which is why I made the edit removing the link.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JoelGritter, I hadn't noticed that documentation is in the process of being dropped. I removed the link 