# Handling missing image resources during Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know I can handle missing image error with jQuery like this:

```
$('img').on('error', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', '/image-placeholder.svg');
});
```

This works just fine on page load. However, I have an Ajax call that returns HTML string to be placed on the page. The HTML also has images in it that might be missing. **For the Ajax case the code above does not work**: the missing resources are throwing 404 but they are not replaced by the placeholder. I tried to use event delegation, but no luck:

```
$(document).on('error', 'img', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', '/image-placeholder.svg');
});
```

Is there a way to handle the missing resources after they've been returned via Ajax response?

My Ajax call uses the `$.get()` method.

Comment: Place your code in ajax success event right after set HTML.

Comment: Can you please share your ajax request code?

Comment: `$.ajax` `.error` handler is not handling 404? Maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Can you display your ajax call please. You might want to check the image exists..... maybe something like this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript unless its the ajax returning the 404 then you can use the error handler `.error` or `.fail` depending on your setup in your ajax call.

Comment: the load event does not bubble so you can't delegate the event

Comment: As far as I know, the `.error()` and `.fail()` methods both indicate that the Ajax call *itself* failed (response code other than 200). My requests succeeds, but the problem lies in the returned HTML, as I wrote.

Comment: You can register a global handler for all image loading errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load event does not bubble so you can't delegate the event, you can bind the error event again after you appended the html to the page

Answer (score 1):

You can register a global handler for all image loading errors (you’ll need to use a capturing listener):

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'error',
    function(event){
        var target = event.target;
        if( target.tagName == 'IMG'){
         console.log("your code here");
        }
    },
    true // <-- useCapture
)
```