# Alternate/Fallback Image while using Snap SVG

Tags: javascript, image, svg, snap.svg

I have just downloaded Snap SVG and I'm trying to figure out how to display an image with a fall back arrangement. Here is the code:

```
var s = Snap("#MyPopup");
var g = s.g();
var image = g.image("http://myimages.com/xyz.png", 250, 10, 40,40 );
```

This displays the image perfectly. However, if the image is missing then you get that broken image-not-fond icon. Instead of that I want to display an alternate image, say http://myimages.com/abc.png , if the primary image is not found (similar to onerror used with `<img>`). Can someone please guide me how to do that.

Comment: You want to check to make sure the image exists, and then display it only if it exists. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript -- check for the image, then wrap your g.image statement in an if statement and display the replacement image if the first one is not found.

Comment: Thanks @AustimC. That was helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking cue from @AustinC I have slightly modified the solution given at [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript) that he suggested.

Basically the suggested function was returning 403 (instead of 404) as my images were hosted at amazon cloud, hence I opted to check return code 200 (OK). Here is the final solution.

```
var s = Snap("#MyPopup");
var image = null;
var mImagePath = "https://myimages.com/xyz.png";

if ( imageExists (mImagePath) == true ) {
    image = s.image(mImagePath, 250, 10, 40,40 );                   
} else {
    image = s.image("https://myimages.com/ImageNotFound.png", 250, 10, 40,40 );
}


function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status == 200;

}
```