# How to check whether image exist using chai or mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Using Chai or mocha, how can I see whether an image exists. For example, [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png)

Comment: Can you expand on what do you mean by exists?

Comment: I'm assuming you are writing a test and want to assert that something happens with an image?

Comment: I expect the test to return 200 or status ok

Comment: hm, are you trying to test something like cdn assets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript)

Comment: I am trying to test images on my website which has a URL.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of the above mentioned link. They haven't used any testing framework there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [chai http](http://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) plugin:

```
it('should check image', function(done) {
  chai.request('https://upload.wikimedia.org')
  .get('/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png')
  .end(function(err, res) {
    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    done();                               
  });
});
```