# VUE- How to stop loading images if (they) do not exist?

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of images. So, what I want to do is load images if only it exists. I tried several methods but that didn't work at all.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    images: [
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      '200x200',
      'noxno', //invalid image
      'noxno', //invalid image
      'noxno', //invalid image
      'noxno' //invalid image
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <img v-for="image in images" :src="'https://via.placeholder.com/' + image" alt="">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ya2r34zj/3/

Comment: How do you know that the image doesn't exist? does the array send `'noxno'`  everytime image is not present

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript