# How to display div only when img src exist?

Tags: jquery, css

```
<a class="thumbnail-link" href="">
<div id="thumbnail-wrap" class="thumbnail-wrap">
<img width="600" height="360" src="image.jpg">
</div>
</a>
```

How do I show thumbnail-link div if there is image?

Opossite solution would be...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $(".thumb-summary").find("img[src='']").parent().hide();

});
</script>
```

But than, its visible on page load that it hides divs without image and looks bad.
I want to make it only show images if it finds them, jquery way please.

Comment: use css `img[src=''] {display : none; }`

Comment: I need to hide parent div because of its css.

Comment: How is markup generated? Seems cleaner not to render the `<img>` and parent if there is no `src`

Comment: Check this answer to know if the image exists : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially hide all the parent element which is `.thumbnail-wrap` using CSS 
and later show elements which have an attribute value, use [`:not()` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to ignore all `img` tag with `src` empty.

**CSS :**

```
.thumb-summary .thumbnail-wrap{
   display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".thumb-summary").find("img:not([src=''])").parent().show();
    // or 
    //  $(".thumb-summary .thumbnail-wrap:has(img:not([src='']))").show();
});
```

---

***FYI :*** If you have access to backend code then add some class to the parent element based on src and add style to that particular class(for hiding).

Comment: Works! Fix dispaly:hide; to display: none; .