# How do I look through multiple addresses for src in img tag?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am working on a project built in Laravel 5.8 where i need to look through 3 different image Sources for an `img` tag. 
For example first I will put `src` of "https://yw-web.yoworld.com/cdn/items/12/73/127305/127305.png"
if this does not return an image then i will provide second address like
"https://yw-web.yoworld.com/cdn/items/12/73/127305/127305_130_100.gif"
if still no image found I will try third address like
"https://yw-web.yoworld.com/cdn/items/12/73/127305/127305_60_60.gif"
and if all three of these does not work then this image will be loaded
"https://yoworld.info/assets/image_not_found.jpg"

recently I have implemented this snippet which seems to work fine but it is taking a lot of time to execute.

```
HTML:
<img class="my-auto mx-auto" src="{{$img}}">


PHP:
$src= 'https://yw-web.yoworld.com/cdn/items/12/73/127305/127305';
if(@getimagesize($src.'.png')){
$img=$src.'.png';
}
elseif(@getimagesize($src.'_130_100.gif')){
$img=$src.'_130_100.gif';
}
elseif(@getimagesize($src.'_60_60.gif')){
$img=$src.'_60_60.gif';
}
else{
$img=url('img/image_not_found.jpg');
}
```

file_exists() does not work because I am accessing these images from another domain and cURL is also taking a lot of time.

Kindly suggest me an approach which takes less time. I can also use Javascript it provides a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$file = 'http://www.someAddress.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: Taking more than 1 minute for 12 Images.

Comment: @HamzaSaeed the CURL take time too much, you can do it in jquery, after page load you can run this function in jquery and get the image `this is my opinion, it maybe wrong`

Answer (score 0):

Look through this answer:

> [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript/18837818)

Maybe it help.