# How to check if an image is available and display it with v-if

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2

How do I check if an image is available and render it if so?

So far I have tried something like this, but does not give a true condition.

```
<div v-for="owner in organisation.owners"
    <div v-if="`https://intranet.com/Lists/CustomPortraits/${owner.employeeId}.jpg`" :style="`background-image:url(https://intranet.com/Lists/CustomPortraits/${owner.employeeId}.jpg)`" class="user-profile-image"/>
    <div v-else class="user-avatar"> <span/>{{ owner.name | nameInitials }} </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript)

Comment: An how to do this the best way in vue.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking image exists on the server in JS is well described in another SO question - [Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837735/381282)

So it is easy just to choose one of the solutions and integrate it into Vue. Since you want to use it in the `v-for` loop, plain function is a bad solution. Better will be to introduce `computed` property and extend existing object with some new properties:

### Update

*Deleted my previous code* - `computed` is a bad choice either in this case because array/objects returned from `computed` prop is not reactive data (changing the content of object returned by `computed` will NOT trigger Vue re-render)

New example below shows solution combining deep watching input data (`organisation`) + maintaining extended data in the `data` part of the component...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      // this if external input in question (prop maybe)
      organisation: {
        owners: [{
            employeeId: 100,
            name: "Bill",
          },
          {
            employeeId: 200,
            name: "Murray",
            fail: true // just for demo purposes
          },
          {
            employeeId: 300,
            name: "Billy",
          },
        ]
      },
      ownersWithImage: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkImageExists(owner) {
      const img = new Image()
      img.onload = () => {
        owner.doesImageExist = true
      }
      img.onerror = () => {
        owner.doesImageExist = false
      }
      img.src = owner.imageUrl
    },
    extendOwnerWithImage(owner) {
      const extendedOwner = {
        ...owner,
        imageUrl: 'https://www.fillmurray.com/250/' + owner.employeeId,
        doesImageExist: false // default
      }
      if (!owner.fail) // just for demo purposes
        this.checkImageExists(extendedOwner)

      return extendedOwner
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'organisation.owners': {
      handler: function() {
        this.ownersWithImage = this.organisation.owners.map(this.extendOwnerWithImage)
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.user-profile-image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="owner in ownersWithImage" :key="owner.employeeId">
    <div v-if="owner.doesImageExist" :style="`background-image:url(${owner.imageUrl})`" class="user-profile-image">
      <span>{{ owner.name }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="user-profile-image"><span>{{ owner.name }}</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```